# Map.Entry<?,?> returns as object [Bukkit plugin loader, AddonDescriptionFile]

Tags: java, bukkit

In code:

```
for (Map.Entry<?,?> command : ((Map)map.get("commands")).entrySet()) {
    ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> commandBuilder = ImmutableMap.builder();
    if (command.getValue() != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> commandEntry : ((Map)command.getValue()).entrySet()) {
            if ((commandEntry.getValue() instanceof Iterable)) {
                ImmutableList.Builder<Object> commandSubList = ImmutableList.builder();
                for (Object commandSubListItem : (Iterable)commandEntry.getValue()) {
                    if (commandSubListItem != null) {
                        commandSubList.add(commandSubListItem);
                    }
                }
                commandBuilder.put(commandEntry.getKey().toString(), commandSubList.build());
            }
            else if (commandEntry.getValue() != null) {
                commandBuilder.put(commandEntry.getKey().toString(), commandEntry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    commandsBuilder.put(command.getKey().toString(), commandBuilder.build());
}
```

The second Map.Entry returns as Object but the first one works fine?

any help?

```
ERROR: Required: Map.Entry<?, ?>
       Found: Object
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: after copying it here ,select all code and press `ctrl+k` it will format automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like without specifying *any* type parameters at all, `Map.entrySet()` returns just a plain unparameterized `Set`. To get a `Set<Map.Entry<?,?>>`, you have to at least use wildcard type parameters, i.e. cast to `Map<?,?>`

```
for (Map.Entry<?, ?> commandEntry : ((Map<?,?>) command.getValue()).entrySet()) {
```